# Can I style the top-level form in Designer preview?

Tags: preview, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

In Qt Designer, I've set a default print/preview stylesheet in the Preferences, to match the stylesheet of the application that will contain my UIs.  When previewing, all of the contained widgets are styled correctly, but my top-level form isn't.  Why?  And what can I do?

For example, using this stylesheet:

```
MyFormBase
  { background: black; color: white; }

QLabel
  { background: transparent; color: yellow; }
```

and a UI structure like

- **MyForm** `form` (subclass of MyFormBase)

  - **QLabel** `label`

The label has yellow text, but it's displayed on Designer's default (grey) background.

Answer (score 0):

When the Designer creates a preview, it constructs a plain `QWidget` as the top level window.  So any style applied using the class name of the top-level form doesn't match.

Examination of Designer's internals shows that it applies a property to mark the top-level window; we can select using that to style the top-level form:

```
[_q_custom_style_disabled="true"], /* for preview in Designer */
MyFormBase
  { background: black; color: white; }

QLabel
  { background: transparent; color: yellow; }
```

Note that the `_q_custom_style_disabled` property is not a documented feature of Designer, so it may be subject to change without warning.

---

If you have many selectors that depend on top widget (e.g. if you have `MyFormBase > QLabel`), or if you're concerned about the hack above, you might want to apply a custom property:

```
[role~=Page"]
  { background: black; color: white; }

[role~=Page"] > QLabel
  { background: transparent; color: yellow; }
```

Obviously, you then have to remember to apply the property to the topmost widget on each of your forms!